# SQL Server Error: "Must Declare Scalar Variable"

Tags: sql-server

Really silly, but I'm trying to come up with an SQL Server script that creates a stored procedure that decreases the RackRate of a hotel room by 6.66%.  When I go to execute the stored procedure, I keep getting the following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable '@NewRackRate'.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = 'sp_UpdateRackRate')
    DROP PROCEDURE sp_UpdateRackRate;
GO

CREATE PROC sp_UpdateRackRate
    @RackRate smallmoney
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewRackRate smallmoney;
    DECLARE @OldRackRate smallmoney = (SELECT RackRate FROM RackRateTable);

    UPDATE RackRateTable
    SET @NewRackRate = @OldRackRate - (@OldRackRate * .0666)
END
GO

EXEC sp_UpdateRackRate
      @RackRate = @NewRackRate;    // How do I access @NewRackRate?
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, you want @NewRackRate to be an OUTPUT parameter in the stored procedure.

Comment: @NewRackRate is declared after BEGIN, and goes out of scope when the corresponding END is reached. You can only use it while it's in scope. One the END is reached, it no longer exists and you can't use it in the EXEC call.

Comment: @KenWhite, that's what I figured.  How to I declare it globally?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Your procedure doesn't make sense at all. First, unless `RackRateTable` contains only one row, your second declare should return an error. Second, Your update statement is setting a variable instead of a column, and third, your parameter should probably be declared as an output parameter, as ZLK wrote.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = 'sp_UpdateRackRate')
    DROP PROCEDURE sp_UpdateRackRate;

GO

CREATE PROC sp_UpdateRackRate
    @RackRate           smallmoney

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @NewRackRate smallmoney;
DECLARE @OldRackRate smallmoney = (SELECT Top 1 RackRate FROM RackRate);

UPDATE RackRateTable
    SET NewRackRate = @OldRackRate - (@OldRackRate * .0666)

END
select (@OldRackRate - (@OldRackRate * .0666)) NewRackRate
GO

EXEC sp_UpdateRackRate 100.06
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to output @NewRackRate from your stored procedure. Based on the example provided, here's a quick way you could do it...

```
CREATE PROC sp_UpdateRackRate
      @NewRackRate smallmoney OUTPUT
AS BEGIN
    SELECT @NewRackRate = RackRate * 0.0334 FROM RackRateTable;
END
GO

DECLARE @RackRate smallmoney;
EXEC sp_UpdateRackRate @RackRate OUTPUT;
--SELECT @RackRate;
```

Realistically, though, you don't need a stored procedure for this. Simply,

```
DECLARE @RackRate smallmoney;
SELECT @RackRate = RackRate * 0.0334 FROM RackRateTable;
--SELECT @RackRate;
```

Comment: Thank you, @ZLK!  What I want to do is UPDATE the RackRateTable and then show my results by writing SELECT * FROM RackRateTable.  How would you do it that way?

Comment: If you want to update the RackRateTable, so that the RackRates are 0.0334 * the current RackRate, you could just do a simple update procedure. e.g. `UPDATE RackRateTable SET RackRate = 0.0334 * RackRate;` If you want to store the previous values for comparison, you can output the results of the update procedure, or create an additional column to store the old value, and update that column to be the current rackrate, e.g `SET OldRackRate = RackRate, RackRate = 0.0334 * RackRate`

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
drop table rackratetable;
create Table rackratetable (ID int ,rackrate smallmoney)
truncate table rackratetable
insert into rackratetable values (1,100.00)

drop procedure PUpdateRAckRAte ;
CREATE procedure PUpdateRackRate 
@adjustment smallmoney ,                --input parameter
@updatedrackrate smallmoney OUTPUT      --output parameter
as

update  rackratetable
    set rackrate = rackrate * @adjustment

select @updatedrackrate = rackrate from rackratetable
--select @updatedrackrate
return

*/
set nocount on
truncate table rackratetable
insert into rackratetable values (1,100.00)

declare @newrate smallmoney
exec  PUpdateRackRate 
    @adjustment = 0.666,                      --Input parameter
    @updatedrackrate     = @newrate OUTPUT    --Returned from procedure note the counterintuitiveness

select 'Updated rack rate is ' + cast(@newrate as varchar(max))
```